# Custom Admin page using add_menu_page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have developed a plugin to write my own customized functions and its already activated. I want to add 1 page on the admin dashboard and using below code but it doesn't seem to be working

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'addAdminPage');
function addAdminPage() {
  add_menu_page('Status Page', 'Status Menu', 'manage_options', '__FILE__', 'AdminPage', 'dashicons-wordpress',90);
}
function AdminPage() {
  echo 'Hello';
}
```

Comment: You are calling the `add_menu_page` wrong. Check: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/

Comment: @user1165759. Which part? I already checked this function and even after multiple tweaks, couldn't figure out. Not sure how to debug it. Not getting any error anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say it's not working but you haven't told us what the error is.  Regardless, if you use this, it should work:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'addAdminPage' );
function addAdminPage(){
    add_menu_page( 
        __( 'Status Page', 'yourplugintextdomain' ),
        'Status Menu',
        'manage_options',
        'statuspage',
        'AdminPage',
        'dashicons-wordpress',
        90
    ); 
}
function AdminPage(){
    esc_html_e( 'Hello', 'yourplugintextdomain' );  
}
```

You shouldn't be attempting to use the `( __FILE__ )` as the slug, so I just made it `statuspage`.  Whenever you're writing custom functionality like this, try to prefix everything with something that relates it back to your plugin.  Like: `lrnr_statuspage` and name your functions stuff like `lrnr_AdminPage` that way you reduce the risk of running into conflicts. Include your plugin or theme's text domain as well to make what you're building translation ready.  It's just good practice.

**Update/Correction:**

I had the function name incorrect.  It will work now.

Here is it running on a site I'm currently developing, I just added the above block of code to the bottom of my `functions.php` and added your username to the 'Hello' message.

[image: Preview of what the snippet will display.]

Comment: I was not using yourplugintextdomain till now, but have added now as per below link. But still it is not working. I am not getting any error, not sure, how to debug it. [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/)

Comment: Sorry, I had the function name incorrect and have edited my answer, please try again.

Comment: Page is not added on my admin dashboard. May be I am not looking at right location??

Comment: I added a preview image after I tested your code on a site I'm working on.

Comment: The code works when I add it in functions.php of my theme's folder but it doesnt work when I use it in my plugin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213560/discussion-between-tony-djukic-and-learner).

Comment: The issue was calling the function at the bottom of my plugin, have moved to the top. It works now.